# Fixing win32Exeption in Unity for Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've ported my Unity project from PC to Mac and now I can't compile muy builds, I get the following error:

`Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/Users/josephtripp/Library/Android/sdk/tools/aapt', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Users/josephtripp/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.everyplay.Everyplay:com.unity3d.ads.android -S "/Users/josephtripp/sens-rebooted/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/everyplay/res" -S "/Users/josephtripp/sens-rebooted/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'`

I've tried reimporting all assets but I can't seem to fix it, anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for such.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after updating android SDK

goto androidsdk\build-tools\19.1.0 (what ever is your version) and copy aapt.exe  to  androidsdk\tools\ and paste aapt.exe and now try building for android